# Use volume key while screen locked

Tags: android

This code doesn't work will screen locked. what should I do if I want volume key work while screen locked?

My code is :

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                //TODO
            }
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //TODO
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can register `BroadcastReceiver` with action "android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION" :

```
android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION
```

Other way of doing is:  [volume key on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220556/taking-over-the-volume-key-on-android) .

Comment: my code actually work fine but the problem is, it doesn't work while screen locked. what I have to do? if it's possible please give me an example. thank you.

Comment: it's not working. I created a BroadCastReceiver and it's working fine while the phone is not locked, but as soon as phone get lock then I can't capture if the key pressed. do you have any idea?

Comment: @mrsh did you find a solution for that? I am facing the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately, no. if you find anything please keep me posted. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Do this in a service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    final BroadcastReceiver vReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             //your code here
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(vReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION"));
}

}
```

Then register BroadcastReceiver with action `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` to play a silent sound continuously when screen is off and action `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` to stop music when screen on. Volume buttons are only active when there's music playing.

Comment: Thank you so much, how can I play silent sound continuously?

Comment: You can use SoundPool, MediaPlayer or ToneGenerator. With the two formers, download a blank music file from here http://www.xamuel.com/blank-mp3s/ ,use SoundPool.play(load, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1) or MediaPlayer.setLooping(true) and .setVolume(0,0) to play silent and continuous sound. With ToneGenerator, use ToneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_DIAL_TONE_LITE).
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html