# Use volume keys when phone is locked in android devices

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-mediaplayer

before everything, I search in this site and google but I still have problem , so I need your help please.

I want to know how can I use volume keys while phone is Locked?
I'm using this code and while phone is not locked it's work good but not when it's locked.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)) {
        // Do something

        // return true because we want handle this key
        return true;
    }
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)) {
        // Do something

        // return true because we want handle this key
        return true;
    }
```

I know I have to use BroadcastReceiver for this matter. but, I want to know how?
if you guys give me live example or some kind of tutorial that I can use.

I added this to my manifest file

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".CountReciever"
        android:process=":remote" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="AddedCounting" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and created this activity

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class CountReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent k2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(context, "received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("in REceiver", "OHAAAHA");
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,AddedCounting.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);  
}
}
```

and in AddedCounting activity I have the piece of code that I added at the beginning of this post to control volume keys.

but it's still not working. if you guys can help on it I really appreciate it.

Last but not least, I don't receive any error.

Thank you for all of your help and time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350675/use-volume-key-while-screen-locked

Comment: Thank you. I saw that post before and I don't want use service, I want to use BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Anything guys? I need help please ....

Comment: Use broadcast receiver for now looks like only way

Comment: Heyy got something try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277164/detect-volume-button-press-when-screen-off

Comment: Can I ask you some question in chat? please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76292/discussion-between-m-r-sh-and-apk).

Comment: while I'm waiting for apk help, is anyone else have anything to help please?

Comment: Hi guys, anything? any update?

Comment: No, I did some research while I was waited for you, but no luck. Do you have any idea?

Comment: unfortunately havent got any thing people are saying its not possible but I have posted separate question for it lets see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917764/android-volume-key-is-not-working-when-screen-is-off

Comment: Do you have the Wake Up permission?

Comment: @joaquin Thank you, Yes I have this permision. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />. Do you have any other idea?