# Android: How to control volume: if volume button up, SeekBar up

Tags: android, volume, seekbar

I have the following code for my **SeekBar**:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            int curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.dialog_root_element));


            SeekBar volControl = (SeekBar)alert.findViewById(R.id.dialog_seekbar);

            volControl.setMax(maxVolume);
            volControl.setProgress(curVolume);
            volControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, arg1, 0);
                }
            });
```

The problem is that I would like when user decide use volume device buttons, my **SeekBar** up or down too.

Actually, with this code I can control volume with both methods (device buttons and code) correctly,but when I use volume device buttons, my **SeekBar** is static.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve this problem by reading the following discussions.

[Is there a listener to listen for changes in the volume in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180279/is-there-a-listener-to-listen-for-changes-in-the-volume-in-android)

[Taking over the volume key on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220556/taking-over-the-volume-key-on-android)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check Following Answer :

```
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
          if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) 
         { 
              mediaVlmSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
                int index = mediaVlmSeekBar.getProgress(); 
                mediaVlmSeekBar.setProgress(index + 1); 
                return true; 
         } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
          {
                int index = mediaVlmSeekBar.getProgress(); 
                mediaVlmSeekBar.setProgress(index - 1); 
                return true; 
         }
          return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
         }
```