# Android: sync system volume seekbar and app seekbar

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager, android-seekbar, android-os-handler

I am trying to sync the system volume seekbar with the application seekbar.

[image: System volume seekbar]
System volume seekbar.

[image: App volume seekbar]
App volume seekbar.

I found a useful link.

[Taking over the volume key on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220556/taking-over-the-volume-key-on-android)

Following, I am able to make my app seekbar change whenever users press the volume button.

My questions are: 
1/ Is it able to sync the system volume seekbar with the app volume seekbar? I mean when users change the seekbar (not pressing the button), my app volume seekbar also changes too. 
2/ If the question 1 is "yes", please show me the way. I found some links which suggest to use `registerMediaButtonEventReceiver`, but it is already deprecated.

## EDIT

Here is what I am doing right now: 
1/ I used `MediaPlayer` to play an audio 
2/ I used `AudioManager` to manage the volume whenever the seekbar change 
3/ I used `onKeyUp` and `onKeyDown` to detect the action pressing volume button 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: see `android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompatApi8#registerMediaButtonEventReceiver`

Comment: @pskink: Can you show me how to do it. I start researching but there are not many documents which are able to solve my problem. I am also appreciated if you can leave your full answer. Thank you

Comment: just like deprecated `AudioManager#registerMediaButtonEventReceiver` (the method signature is the same so it should work the same way)